# Online Education for OR and Developing Decision Support Systems

Tags: optimization, online-resources, column-generation, metaheuristics, reinforcement-learning

I am looking for educational programmes which can be conducted online, such as

- full MSc., degree certificates,
- postgraduate courses/modules,
- MOOCs.

Topics I am looking for are on advanced optimization such as

- column generation,
- (meta)heuristics,
- reinforcement learning.

Any recommendations? Feel free to share experiences!

Longer background: I have an MSc. in Engineering during which I focussed on optimization methods (MILP, heuristics, queuing models etc.) in a specific sector. At my work, I get the freedom to develop myself further into the field with the goal of being able to develop (prototype) tooling for decision support at our clients.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check Coursera, edX, Udemy, or any other online courses (such as those of Stanford). For example:

- Free: [Discrete Optimization](https://www.coursera.org/learn/discrete-optimization) course on Coursera, covers column generation and an introduction to (meta)heuristic
- [Optimization with Metaheuristics in Python](https://www.udemy.com/optimization-with-metaheuristics/) on Udemy
- Lectures of [Introduction to Meta-heuristics](https://www.u-aizu.ac.jp/~qf-zhao/TEACHING/MH/mh.html)
- [Artificial Intelligence: Reinforcement Learning in Python](https://www.udemy.com/course/artificial-intelligence-reinforcement-learning-in-python/) and [Advanced AI: Deep Reinforcement Learning in Python](https://www.udemy.com/deep-reinforcement-learning-in-python/) are intermediate and advanced courses on Udemy (by the same instructor.)
- Also, check the great answers already provided in other questions on the site. For example, [Good resources for solving techniques (Metaheuristics, MILP, CP etc)](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/971/good-resources-for-solving-techniques-metaheuristics-milp-cp-etc) and [Linear and Integer programming materials](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/linear-and-integer-programming-materials/1325#1325).

Answer (score 6):

For heuristics you can take a look at this [course](https://homes.di.unimi.it/righini/Didattica/AlgoritmiEuristici/MaterialeAE/MaterialeAE.htm). Also the book "[How to solve it : Modern heuristics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540224947)" by Zbigniew Michalewicz and David B. Fogel.

Reinforcement Learning has similiarities with approximate dynamic programming, these [video lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CaUxbFX8Oc&list=PLiCLbsFQNFAxOmVeqPhI5er1LGf2-L9I4) by D. P. Bertsekas may be useful.

Answer (score 5):

#### Institute of Applied Optimization

[Metaheuristic Optimization](http://iao.hfuu.edu.cn/teaching/lectures/metaheuristic-optimization) - prerequisite: Java programming

#### Coursera

[Practical Reinforcement Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/practical-rl) - [related](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/831/suggestion-of-some-courses-in-sequential-decision-making)

Answer (score 4):

For Reinforcement learning and Deep Reinforcement learning, a wonderful online free course on RL by David Silver (the first author of the AlphaZero, AlphaGo algorithms) exists:
[YouTube links](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzuuYNsE1EZAXYR4FJ75jcJseBmo4KQ9-)

A more advanced course by Sergey Levine exists for free at:
[YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkFD6_40KJIxJMR-j5A1mkxK26gh_qg37)

For both course the link to the material of the course is available too.